# How to initialize a BuildType with the configuration of an existing BuildType?

Tags: android, gradle

I want to configure a third BuildType in my project that inherits all the configurations from another BuildType.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the `initWith` property with in the build type:

```
uitesting {
     initWith debug         
}
```

You can find more information on the respectively developer page: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types

As an alternative you can also use:

```
<<new_build_type>>.initWith(buildTypes.<<old_build_type>>)
```

In a real case this looks like:

```
uitesting.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
uitesting {
...         
}
```

Comment: Actually the right way of doing this is `initWith debug`, you guys can read more here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types, using initWith `.initWith(buildTypes.debug)` it fails the compilation

Comment: I just updated my four year old answer with the new information. I think both ways are working and valid, so I don't think there's only "one right way". I don't think the downvote was necessary nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

Use `jnidebug.initWith(buildTypes.debug)` to inherit properties of another build type

Please try something like this

```
    android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

        }

        jnidebug.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
        jnidebug {
            packageNameSuffix ".jnidebug"
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }
}
```

This might be helpful http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types

Answer (score 1):

use `.initWith()`

```
mock.initWith(buildTypes.debug)
```

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types

Answer (score 1):

In the newer developer guide (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants), you can use:

```
android {
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"

    }

    jnidebug {
        initWith debug
        packageNameSuffix ".jnidebug"
        jniDebuggable true
    }
}
}
```